# oracle trigger print after insert

Tags: oracle

I just started learning Trigger. And I want to make a trigger which after insert on test gives user a notice 'insert successfully'.

Here is my code.

```
create table test (id number, name varchar2(30));

create trigger tr_test 
after insert on test
for each row
begin
dbms_output.put_line('insert successfully');
end;
/

insert into test values(1, 'john');
```

And I get the error like this:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table YUFENG.TEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "YUFENG.TR_TEST", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'YUFENG.TR_TEST'
```

Could anyone point out the error and tell me how to modify the code?

---

Sorry that I didn't notice that there are lots of simple mistakes which makes the query not able to run. And my original code declares variable in the trigger, but I didn't post it. I think probably that is the reason why I get the error mutating.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST
AFTER INSERT ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE a VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
SELECT ID INTO a FROM TEST WHERE ID=:NEW.ID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('insert successfully');
END;
/
```

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code which would cause the trigger to mutate. Clearly this is not the code you're running so what is the point? Mutating table questions are fairly common on this site. A simple search for ORA-04091 returns literally hundreds of hits.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem of my original code is probably the same as mutating table question.

Answer (score 1):

the output will only be displayed, if you turn it on (SQL*Plus, SQL*Developer):

set serveroutput on

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete.  There is a missing ")" on the CREATE TABLE.
The putline is misspelled.  It should be PUT_LINE.

It is an extremely bad idea to use DBMS_OUTPUT in a Trigger.  A user may be using a client that cannot or does not handle DBMS_OUTPUT (unlike sqlplus)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `after` with `before` as below, also the table needs ')' missing.

```
create table test (id number, name varchar2(30));


create or replace trigger tr_test 
before insert on test
for each row
begin
dbms_output.put_line('insert successfully');
end;
/
```

also its good idea you specific columns in the insert

```
insert into test (id,name) values(1, 'john')
/
commit
/
```